# Find a smooth function with non smooth inverse

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Maybe I'm asking silly question, but I want to find a smooth function, whose inverse is continuous, but not smooth, preferable a function $\ f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I'm sure there is a ton of these functions. Any help is much obliged.

Comment: Well, you need one whose derivative has at least one zero. Does that give you an idea?

Comment: There is the old cubic counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $f(x) = x^3$ is smooth. Its inverse is continuous on $\Bbb R$, but not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid now... Of course $x^3$ is now obvious choice. Many thanks!

Comment: @markich Happy to help!